# Integral equation

Tags: integral-equations

I'm trying to solve the following integral equation:

```
Integrate[-k/2 Exp[-k Abs[x-z]] f[x], {x,0,d}] == a f[z]
```

Differentiating twice with respect to z should yield the following differential equation if i'm not mistaken (using [Leibniz integral rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign)):

```
a f[z] == Integrate[-k/2 Exp[k (x-z)] f[x], {x,0,z}] + 
    Integrate[-k/2 Exp[-k (x-z)] f[x], {x,z,d}]

a f'[z] == (-k/2 f[z] + Integrate[k^2/2 Exp[k (x-z)] f[x], {x,0,z}]) + 
    (k/2 f[z] + Integrate[-k^2/2 Exp[-k (x-z)] f[x], {x,z,d}]

a f''[z] == (k^2/2 f[z] + Integrate[-k^3/2 Exp[k (x-z)] f[x], {x,0,z}] +     
    (k^2/2 f[z] + Integrate[-k^3/2 Exp[-k (x-z)] f[x], {x,z,d}]

a*f''[z] == k^2 (a+1) f[z]
```

Or

```
f[z] = C[1] Exp[Sqrt[1+1/a] k z] + C[2] Exp[-Sqrt[1+1/a] k z]
```

However, when I specify this function as the input, i.e.

```
f[z_]:= Exp[Sqrt[1+1/a] k z] + Exp[-Sqrt[1+1/a] k z]

Integrate[-k/2 Exp[-k Abs[x-z]] f[x], {x,0,d}, Assumptions->{z \[Element] Reals, 
    z > 0, z < d, k \[Element] Reals, k > 0, d \[Element] Reals} ]
```

I dont get `a*f[z]` back, nor anything similar. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: This is not really an integral equation. The upper limit of the integral has to be `z` in your example, which is the independent variable in `f(z)` for it to be called integral equation? How did you handle the derivative of the absolute term there?

Comment: the z limit is there implicitly, as the absolute value of `x-z` appears in the integrand. I split the integral in two parts (between 0 and z, and z and d).

Comment: I fail to see how differentiating the integral twice should yield k^2 (a+1) f[z]. Could you show how you derived that?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I edited the question to show the derivation steps

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. `C[1]` and `C[2]` are not arbitrary, but they are determined by the boundary conditions, `f[0]` and `f[d]`. Taking this into account the solution is `C[1]=C[2]=0`, and therefore `f[z]==0`.

Comment: i was just about to ask how the solution can not depend on `d`…